# Is there a way to make an SSH session act like a local terminal session?

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, xorg

Some of the commands I run want to be run from the X11 display.

Examples:

I have to specify the display to run anything with [`xset`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xset). I can’t run vbetool remotely (no display switch). Starting any graphical program doesn’t know what display I want it to run on by default.

The box I’m SSH’d into is a HTPC and any command I run via SSH should use 0:0. Some way to make this work by default?

Comment: Are you asking how to run a program which requires X, but you only have command line /tty over SSH? i.e., you can't run the command, because the program is expecting it to be run in a GUI?

Comment: I want the ssh session to behave like it's a terminal session run inside X.

Comment: that is not clear, can you try explaining another way- you want to start a GUI program from the command line? or you want to direct the output of a command line to an existing X session?

Comment: I want to be able to do anything inside an ssh session to my HTPC that I could do if I had a terminal open on that machine within the X session. I _think_ that if the default display for the SSH session was 0:0 that would solve most of my problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a bit of reading I figured out how to get what I wanted.

Once I'm connected via ssh I run

```
$ export DISPLAY=0:0
```

That seems to set the default display to the server's display and programs stop nagging me about not being able to find a display to use.

Answer (score 0):

you could use "ssh -X" to tunnel X to your local XServer.

you can try XDMCP.
https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Installation_Guide/s2-trouble-remotex.html

Or you can try "xauth" to access an existing XCookie to use on a remote XServer.

but I guess you cannot send xprograms to a remote XServer via SSH without some kind of authorization to the XServer.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_authorization

hth

Comment: I tried ssh -X. I'm not _exactly_ sure how it works and it kind of scares me. Anyway, it seems to be the opposite of what I was looking to do. (close tho!)

Comment: ssh -X sends the graphical output(!) of any program you started on the remote server (you logged in with ssh) to your local maschine. to make this work your local maschine needs a running Xserver like X.org on Linux or Xvncsrv or XMing on Windows. take a look at the wiki. No XServer will allow anonymous connections! You can log in with ssh to a remote SSH Server but not a remote XServer.